# Can you save your progress in the Grognak minigame?

Tags: fallout-4

The Fallout 4 minigames can be long enough that you might not want to complete them in one sitting - can you 'save' your progress in them some how?

In perticular there is a holotype game with Groknak which seems to be long.

Comment: What mini games are you referring to?

Comment: @DangerZone Probably referring to the [Grognak one](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Grognak_%26_the_Ruby_Ruins), the others finish pretty quickly

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault - Right! I totally forgot about those... Probably doesn't help that I only ran into one in two playthroughs..

Comment: Yeah sorry, the holotape games.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The game saves your progress automatically when you quit.

To be certain all your progress is saved correctly, be sure your character is located on the overworld (the map where you can move your character). Once you boot up the holotape once again, you'll have the option to continue your game:

[image: Grognak start screen]

Your character will be located outside of the tavern, where you started.